# Hover effect doesnot work with Transform: rotateY

Tags: javascript, css, transform

Hello I have changed the flip card element from w3schools and added javascript that they will rotate 60px if they are in viewport with that user can understand that there is a textt behind card. It works well on scroll but now I release that hover effekt is not working.Can you please help me?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

https://jsfiddle.net/mqbkzLy2/

```js
var x = 0;
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(".flip-card-inner").isInViewport() && x == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".flip-card-inner").css('transform', 'rotateY(80deg)');
    }, 400);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".flip-card-inner").css('transform', 'rotateY(0)');
    }, 800);
    x++;
    console.log(x);
    console.log("in");
  }
  if (!$(".flip-card-inner").isInViewport() && x != 0) {
    x = 0;
    console.log('No success.');
    console.log(x);
    console.log("out");

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:120vh;background-color:yellow;"></div>
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Windows_live_square.JPG" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, could you try inserting your snippet to the special runnable snippet using `Ctrl+M`? It's easier to run your code that way ;-)

Comment: You can run my code easily with that second link jsfiddle

Comment: its because you are setting and inline style for the html, you can overwrite it by adding `!important`  `.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

> that they will rotate 60px if they are in viewport with that user can understand that there is a textt behind card.

Don't use scroll event listener for this, use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this.

IO was designed for such problems. With IO you can react whenever an HTML element intersects with another one (or with the viewport)

[Check this page](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/), it shows you how to animate an element once it comes into viewport (scroll all the way down). Of course, you can use any animation you want, this is then handled by CSS. This is just an really visible example.

Short recap on what you have to do to get IO to work:

First you have to create a new observer:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we define that once your target Element is 100% visible in the viewport (threshold of 1) your callback Function is getting executed. Here you can define another percentage, 0.5 would mean that the function would be executed once your element is 50% visible.

Then you have to define which elements to watch

```
var target = document.querySelector('.flip-card');
observer.observe(target);
```

Last you need to specify what should happen once the element is visible in your viewport by defining the callback function:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // here you animate another element and do whatever you like
  });
};
```

If you need to support older browsers, use the [official polyfill from w3c.](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)

If you don't want to trigger the animation again when the elements are scrolled again into view a second time then you [can also unobserve an element](http://%20%20[3]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) once it's animated.